# Can anyone tell how to program a Binary Search in Windows Forms pls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, binary-search

Does anyone know how to make a binary search in windows form application (C#) without doing the insert part? I need to search from a list of allItems.

Comment: `SortedSet` is the .Net Name for "BinaryTree": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try This it shows the index output:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace BinarySearchmethod
{
    class AKSHAY
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
            int index1 = list.BinarySearch("C");
            Console.WriteLine("Index 1: {0}", index1);
            int index2 = list.BinarySearch("F");
            Console.WriteLine("Index 2 : {0} ", index2);
            int index3 = list.BinarySearch("H");
            Console.WriteLine("Index 3 : {0} ", index3); 
            // wait for input before exiting
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to finish");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:-

[image]

[Binary Search Tree Implementation in C#](http://www.bluesharktutorials.com/2013/09/binary-search-tree-implementation-in-c-sharp.html)

Comment: Any idea of how to not do it hardcoded? I mean, I need to insert a string of words in a textbox and display the result (which is a string of words) in a listbox. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the List class it has a binary search method that returns an index. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.